# How to get extended Android software version?

Tags: android

For example HTC Evo 4G has Android version 2.3.5, its software version can be 4.67.651.3 (for HTC Evo 4G)

how should I programatically get this software version value?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
    String productVersion = "";
    Process ifc = null;
    try {
        ifc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("getprop ro.product.version");
        BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ifc.getInputStream()), 2048);
        productVersion = bis.readLine();

    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
        if (ifc != null) {
            ifc.destroy();
        }
    }
```

This will give you the value you are looking for. This is device-dependent. You may need to look at the property "ro.build.description" as well.

Answer (score -1):

A snippet from one of my apps to send an email with all the data about the app I need.  Build.VERSION.SDK_INT is the OS version.  I use the ApplicationInfo and PackManager to get some custom data from the manifest where I store non-Android meta-data about the app.

```
ApplicationInfo ai = _context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(_context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

PackageInfo manager= _context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(_context.getPackageName(), 0);
body.append("Application version " + manager.versionName + " - ");
body.append("Content version " + ai.metaData.get("ContentVersion")  + "\n");

body.append("OS Version:" + Build.VERSION.SDK_INT + "\n");
body.append(Build.MANUFACTURER + " - ");
body.append(Build.MODEL + " - ");
body.append(Build.PRODUCT + "\n"  + "\n" + "\n");
```

Comment: The poster isn't looking for the OS version. He wants the software build number. This isn't the correct solution.